# Errata Corridge in Gabor Filter Documentation and Frequency Response

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, gabor

I have a really simple question regarding this [tutorial](http://mplab.ucsd.edu/tutorials/gabor.pdf) I found on Gabor filters.

Check the very beginning section, equations (1), (2), (3) and (4).  Is there any chance that equation (4) is missing an `=` and should be written as follows?

> e^jθ * s(t) = e^j(2πfot+θ) = [sin(2πfot + θ), j cos(2πfot + θ)]

```
          ^
          | 
          |
```

this is the missing `=`

And furthermore, why is the right hand-side of the equation written with the imaginary j multiplying the cosine and not on the sine as in [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)?

Finally can anyone please help me interpret the frequency response of this filter (Sections 1.1 and 1.2)? What does it mean in terms of its frequency response that its Fourier Transform is the one of equation (8)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I guess it only makes sense with '=', but even then I would say $e^{j(2\pi f_ot+\theta)}=\cos(2\pi f_ot+\theta)+j\sin(2\pi f_ot+\theta)$, i.e. I don't get right-hand side.

Comment: @MattL. Some kind of vector notation?

Comment: Could be, but why $j\cos()$?

Comment: @MattL. - yeah, it looks very weird to me...but I'll take it as a typ0, or any kind of better suggestion?

Comment: @geometrikal - I was thinking the same, still I've never encountered it before...